# How to halt a loop in Julia and printing the ErrorMsg at the same time without using any macros?

Tags: julia, newtons-method

I am writing a simple newton method

```
x_(n+1) = x_n - f(x_n) / f_prime(x_n)
```

to find the roots (can be a real number or a complex number) of a quadratic function:

```
f(x) = a*x*x + b*x + c
```

(`a`, `b`, `c` are given constants and are all real numbers). I know Newton method will fail if the start point or some iteration point in the loop has a zero derivative. I want to use a if statement inside my for/while loop to avoid this situation. Does Julia have something like `stop 0` syntax in Fortran ?

The generic Newton's Method root-finding code:

```
function newton_root_finding(f, f_diff, x0, rtol=1e-8, atol=1e-8)
    f_x0 = f(x0)
    f_diff_x0 = f_diff(x0)
    x1 = x0 - f_x0 / f_diff_x0
    f_diff_x1 = f_diff(x1)

    @assert abs(f_diff_x0) > atol + rtol * abs(f_diff_x0) "Zero derivative. No solution found."

    while abs(f_x0) > atol + rtol * (abs(f_x0))
        x0 = x1
        f_x0 = f(x0)
        f_diff_x0 = f_diff(x0)
        x1 = x0 - f_x0 / f_diff_x0
    end

    return x1
end 

function quadratic_func(x)
    a = 1.0
    b = 0.0 
    c = 2.0
    return a*x*x + b*x + c
end

function quadratic_func_diff(x)
    a = 1.0
    b = 0.0 
    c = 2.0   
    return 2.0*a*x + 1.0*b + 0.0*c

end

newton_root_finding(quadratic_func, quadratic_func_diff, 1.0 + 0.5im)
```

In the above code I used a `@assert` macro to make it happens, but I don't want to use any macro. I want to use a if statement inside my while loop to halt it. Another thing I've noticed is that if I change to `@assert abs(f_diff_x0) != 0` this test will be ignored. Is that because of some round-off errors that "zero derivative" doesn't exactly equal to 0?

Comment: using @assert is exactly like using an if statement:
```
julia> @macroexpand @assert True == False "Wrong" 
:(if True == False
      nothing
  else
      (Base.throw)((Base.AssertionError)("Wrong"))
  end)

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to exit from the inside of a loop in general is a `break` statement; a `return` fulfills the same purpose, because it just exits the whole function.

For the comparisons you can use `Base.isapprox(x, y; atol=atol, rtol=rtol)`.  It's documentation starts with:

> Inexact equality comparison: `true` if `norm(x-y) <= max(atol, rtol*max(norm(x), norm(y)))`.

`norm` falls back to `abs` for numbers.  And I think you might have a bug in both comparisons, always comparing the value at `x0` to itself.

As for the breaking on zero derivatives, an `@assert` is, I think, appropriate here: if you get zero derivative, you don't stop iteration and return the result, but you throw an error to signify an infeasible condition.  I'd thus write your function as follows:

```
function newton_root_finding(f, ∂f, x0, rtol=1e-8, atol=1e-8)
    x_old = x0
    y_old = f(x0)

    while true
        df_old = ∂f(x_old)
        @assert !isapprox(df_old, 0, rtol=rtol, atol=atol) "Zero derivative. No solution found."

        x_new = x_old - y_old / df_old
        y_new = f(x_new)

        isapprox(y_old, y_new, rtol=rtol, atol=atol) && return x_new

        x_old, y_old = x_new, y_new
    end
end
```

This returns `3.357392012620626e-26 + 1.4142135623730951im` on your test case, approximately `sqrt(2)im`.

Answer (score 2):

To address your first question, you can use `break` to exit the while loop, like

```
function test()
    i = 0
    while true
        i += 1
        if i > 10
            break
        end
    end
    return i
end
```

As to your second question, when comparing floating point numbers it is often better to use `isapprox` (provide an `atol` if you compare against zero) instead of `==` or `!=`.

Comment: Got it, BTW is there any difference between `break` and `exit(code=0)` in Julia?

Comment: Yes, `break` just exits the current loop, while `exit` will end the program ( that is the julia runtime )

Comment: Thanks, for your help.